# R - using LIKE operator with variable

Tags: r, search, desctools

I want to substitute a variable instead of a string in the `%like%` function from `DescTools` package. What I want to do with it after is to have a `loop` where the variable changes value and I get a different results.
I've tried a few ways but can't get it working.
Here is my sample code:

```
    library(DescTools)
    library(dplyr)
    x <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
    y <- c("a","b","c","a","a","a")
    df <- data.frame(x = x, y = y)
    df
```

Here is what I get if I seach for "a" in the `x` column. This is the desired output.

```
 df %>% filter(y %like% "%a%")

# desired output
> df %>% filter(y %like% "%a%")
  x y
1 1 a
2 4 a
3 5 a
4 6 a
```

Now I want to create a variable which will hold the value I want to search

```
   # create a variable which will take out the value I'm looking for
        let <- '"%a%"'
```

If I use that variable in place of the `string`, I get either no result or the wrong result.
Is there any way for me to use a variable insetead of a string?

```
#not working
df %>% filter(y %like% let)

> df %>% filter(y %like% let)
[1] x y
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

#not working
df %>% filter(y %like% cat(let))

> df %>% filter(y %like% cat(let))
"%a%"  x y
1 1 a
2 2 b
3 3 c
4 4 a
5 5 a
6 6 a
```

Comment: This works for me `selectVar <- "%a%"; 

df %>% filter(y %like% selectVar)`

Comment: You've got too many quotes in your assignment: `let <- '"%a%"'` - that will create a string with double quotes inside it which are part of the match. Just do: `let = "%a%"` or `let = '%a%'`

Comment: I tried to overcomplicate things. That worked.

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1**: Evaluate the variable.

```
df %>% filter(y %like% eval(parse(text = let)))
```

**Option 2**: Take advantage of the `filter_` function in `dplyr`.

```
df %>% filter_(paste0("y %like%", let))
```

Edit: actually, the comments are better answers because it's less convoluted---it was the quote level that was the problem.

Comment: No, the OP made a mistake setting their variable `let`. This is not necessary.